# Open webpage with Socks5 proxy in JAVA

Tags: java, proxy, socks

I am trying to open a page URL using Proxy via `Socks5` (Already created on server-side)

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1", 8080));
conn = new URL(urlString).openConnection(proxy);

//Connection
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return (new PasswordAuthentication("user",
                "password".toCharArray()));
    }
};
Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
```

Now I need to open (and closing option?) an URL using this Proxy connection...

Answer (score 0):

> Now I need to open (and closing option?) an URL using this Proxy connection...

You have already done so. Just get the input stream and proceed as usual.

Comment: can you show me how please? :/ You mean, smthg like this: conn.openStream(); ?